# How to lookup and SUM URLs with different paths but same ID in Big Query?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to lookup URLs with the same 'productid=' in Big Query but they may have a different path based on a redesign and new URL format. I'm looking to SUM the clicks for the specific ID if possible.

Example:

- /path-a/productid=12345 (clicks 10)
- /path-b/productid=12345 (clicks
  15)
- /path-c/productid=12345 (clicks 2)

productid=12345 = 27 clicks

I need to match the "productid=" number but unsure of the regex. There's around 9,000 DISTINCT IDs and the integers can range from one digits to six digits.

```
SELECT path, sum(clicks) as clicks, sum(impressions) as impressions
FROM `ecommerce_table` 
WHERE DATE(_PARTITIONTIME) >= "2021-04-01" 
   AND path LIKE '/%/productid=%'
GROUP BY path
ORDER BY clicks DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `r'=(\d+)'`:

```
select regexp_extract('/path-a/productid=12345' , r'=(\d+)')
```

Example of usage:

```
SELECT regexp_extract(path, r'=(\d+)'), sum(clicks) as clicks, sum(impressions) as impressions
FROM `ecommerce_table` 
WHERE DATE(_PARTITIONTIME) >= "2021-04-01" 
   AND path LIKE '/%/productid=%'
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY clicks DESC
```

Comment: There are almost 10,000 different productid numbers. This doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Added example of usage

Comment: WITH
  store_id_data AS (
  SELECT
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(r.page, r"^.*productid=([0-9]+$)") AS store_id,
    r.clicks AS click_value
  FROM

Answer (score 0):

I'd give it the following approach ([SQL Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a4e6376d83b9b5955b468821f4bd2963) for reference):

```
WITH final AS (
  SELECT
    id,
    SUBSTR(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(url, '/', -1), '/', 1), 11) AS product_id,
    url
  FROM your_data
)
SELECT 
    product_id,
    COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS clicks
FROM final
GROUP BY 1
```

Understanding the `id` column as click events, for example, you get to access the URL using `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` and establishing that you are interested in the data between slashes. Then, you apply the `SUBSTR()` function to grab the numbers after `product_id`.

**OUTPUT**:

```
product_id  clicks
----------  ------
12345       5
12346       2
12347       1
```

Comment: I'm limited to the number of rows that I can add to my query. So I unfortunately can't select/union 10,000 unique IDs. I was thinking if there was a regex to match on the ID itself, like '/%/productid=REGEX_HERE'

Comment: The unions are part of the example to recreate the data. You just need to do the query that comes afterwards :)

Comment: I edited the example to make it more clear: you basically want to run this CTE (the query enclosed inside the WITH statement), and then there you have it!